# What's the minimum Angular Rc.X version to use animate?

Tags: angular

What is the minimum Angular 2 RC version to use Angular 2 animations?

I have an an

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/animations.html

```
import {
  Component,
  Input,
  trigger,
  state,
  style,
  transition,
  animate
} from '@angular/core';
```

I've bene trying to use `state` in Angular 2 RC.4 but I got the following error:

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Template parse errors:
Can't bind to '@teamState' since it isn't a known native property

    <img [@teamState]="state1" src="image_url">
<img [@teamState]="state2" src="image2_url">
<img [@teamState]="state3" src="image3_url">
```

Comment: Can you show where and how exactly you use `@teamState`? Also tell which version of angular2 you are using? is it `rc4` now?

Comment: If you are using RC4 its fine. I doubt you should have some problem in implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is with **[@teamState]="..."**

In **RC4**, it should be **@teamState="..."**.

With **RC5** and **later**, it should be **[@teamState]="..."**